# How to use ant.properties in a `vendor.gradle` vendor settings file?

Tags: gradle, ant

I have a multi-project gradle build with an ant build script that contains a task such as this (simplified):

```
<target name="get-version">
  <!-- Goes out and fetches the versioning for each project and sets prop -->
  <property name="version" value="${myDesiredVersion}" />
</target>
```

and inside my build.gradle script I have an ant script loader and then I depend on this target; my issue is that this isn't being evaluated in a way that allows me to use my `ant.properties['version']` in `vendor.gradle` like

```
// version = '1.0.2' -- works
version = ant.properties['version'] // doesn't work
```

I'm a gradle noobie and to top it off I'm migrating an ant project to start using gradle so I could be way off course. It's important to note that I can't just outright include the version in the `vendor.gradle` file since it's being generated by the ant-script.

I'm not familiar with how I could insert this ahead of the gradle lifecycle... I tried something like this

```
gradle.beforeProject { p ->
  tasks['get-version'].execute() // appears to execute successfully?
  configure(p) {
    def vendorSettings = file("${myRoot}/vendor.gradle")
    if(vendorSettings.exists()){
      println "Loading vendor settings for project " + p
      println ant.properties['version'] // but outputs null here
      // ant.properties is still a valid observable map
      apply from: vendorSettings
    }
  }
}
```

and the ant `version` property was still null - note that it works outside of this, I think the scoping is a little different then I think it is in this specific situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have something like

```
task antTask {
  //...

  doLast {
    file("vendor.properties").withInputStream { is ->
      Properties props = new Properties()
      props.load(is)
      props.each { prop -> ext.set(prop.key, prop.value) }
    }
  }
}
```

And after the task is executed you could access properties like `ext.version`, etc.

But, this won't work if you want to use the properties in task configurations, because all the tasks are configured first, only after that are executed if necessary. So your antTask is running only after all other tasks are already configured. So you probably need to rethink how you generate these ant properties and either precompute them before running gradle, or port the logic to gradle build.